# Access the wrong index from an array in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm making a todo list and I have an object in my main component, it looks like this:

```
const todos = ref([
  { name: "Eat lunch", completed: false },
  { name: "Walk the dog", completed: true },
```

I map over it like the following:

```
<div
      v-for="(todo, i) in todos"
      :key="todo.name"
      class="flex w-8/12 justify-between items-center p-6 rounded my-1 ml-1"
      :class="todo.completed ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-red-500'"
      @click="todoStore.showTodoModal()"
    >
      <div v-if="todoStore.todoModal">
        <OpenTask :todo="todo" />
      </div>
      <p>
        {{ todo.name }}
      </p>
      <fa icon="trash" class="mr-2s" @click="remove(i)"></fa>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But when I open up my "OpenTask" modal (that I passed my todo data too), I get the last object in the list showing up, always.

This is the "OpenTask" component:

```
  <template>
  <div
    class="flex fixed top-0 right-0 w-11/12 h-full justify-center items-center"
  >
    <div class="w-9/12 h-3/4 bg-red-400 flex flex-col rounded-xl relative">
      <div class="underline">
        <fa
          @click="todoStore.showTodoModal()"
          icon="circle-xmark"
          class="text-white right-1 top-1 absolute z-20"
        />
        <div></div>

        <h1 class="text-white inline">{{ todo.name }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useTodoStore } from "@/store/TodoStore";

export default {
  props: ["todo"],
  setup(props) {
    const todoStore = useTodoStore();
    console.log(props.todo);
    return { todoStore };
  },
};
</script>
```

I assume I'm not giving the correct index, but I don't know how to do that really.
When I log out the props, both tasks show, but the title (name) of the todo is always the last one in the object array.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd speculate that `showTodoModal()` is an async method, that the loop in the parent is buzzing through todo props, starting an open for each, each one supplanting the one prior, until only the last one remains. So, not about indexing, but rather about async.  Opening a modal in a loop seems inherently wrong.

Comment: This is the function:

import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useTodoStore = defineStore("TodoStore", {
  state: () => ({
    todoModal: false,
  }),

  actions: {
    showTodoModal() {
      this.todoModal = !this.todoModal;
    },
  },
});

Comment: yes, as expected, actions are async.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is your `OpenTask` component's issue, it should be a single instance component. I suggest you can give your `todoStore.showTodoModal()` function a params, eg: index of todos, and const anthoer `const currentTodoIndex = ref(0)` to cache your todo data, like `<OpenTask :todo="todos[currentTodoIndex]" />`

```
const todos = ref([])
const currentTodoIndex = ref(0)

// ...
todoStore.showTodoModal(index) {
 currentTodoIndex.value = index
 //...
} 
//

    <div
      v-for="(todo, i) in todos"
      :key="todo.name"
      :class="todo.completed ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-red-500'"
      class="flex w-8/12 justify-between items-center p-6 rounded my-1 ml-1"
      @click="todoStore.showTodoModal(i)"
    >
      <div v-if="todoStore.todoModal">
        <OpenTask :todo="todos[currentTodoIndex]" />
      </div>
      <p>
        {{ todo.name }}
      </p>
      <fa
        icon="trash"
        class="mr-2s"
        @click="remove(i)"/>
    </div>
```